# VBA for Combining Multiple Worksheets Into One Workbook

Tags: vba, excel

*Running Excel 2016 on PC*

I have been browsing the internet for a few weeks trying to figure this out and I am stuck. I was tasked to take an existing master file with multiple worksheets and split the workbook retaining the worksheets but only show the data for each individual sales rep (over 1000 in our workforce which makes this manual task a huge burden). The master workbook consists of 3 worksheets.

I currently have code written and working that takes the master workbook and splits out the worksheet I have designated for each individual sales rep in our organization and saves the worksheet as a unique file name (code listed below as sub **SplitToFiles**) which I then run for each worksheet in the master file. I would imagine there is some way to loop the initial code is it is written from the get go to split the file for each worksheet and save it as one workbook but I haven't been able to figure this out which is why I went the route of looking for a solution of splitting and then recombining.

Now where I am stuck is getting the new worksheets for the individual rep into a combined file of 1 workbook with all of the worksheets for this rep only. The code I was been able to put together will combine all files in a folder thus defeating my breakout efforts (code listed below as sub **getsheets**).

I would greatly appreciate anyone's help with pointing out where I've gone wrong with this/these codes. I really want to learn!

---

```
Public Sub SplitToFiles()
    Dim osh As Worksheet
    Dim iRow As Long
    Dim iCol As Long
    Dim iFirstRow As Long
    Dim iTotalRows As Long
    Dim iStartRow As Long
    Dim iStopRow As Long
    Dim sSectionName As String
    Dim rCell As Range
    Dim owb As Workbook
    Dim sFilePath As String
    Dim iCount As Integer
    iCol = Application.InputBox("Enter the column number used for splitting", "Select column", 2, , , , , 1) 'The starting column position varies from worksheet to worksheet
    iRow = Application.InputBox("Enter the starting row number (to skip header)", "Select row", 5, , , , , 1) 'The starting row position varies from worksheet to worksheet
    iFirstRow = iRow
    Set osh = Workbooks("Master Workbook.xlsm").Worksheets(1) 'Worksheet number is updated to 2 and 3 to be run for each worksheet on the master workbook.
    Set owb = Application.ActiveWorkbook
    iTotalRows = osh.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    sFilePath = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path
    If Dir(sFilePath + "\Split", vbDirectory) = "" Then
        MkDir sFilePath + "\Split"
    End If
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Do
        Set rCell = osh.Cells(iRow, iCol)
        sCell = Replace(rCell.Text, " ", "")
        If sCell = "" Or (rCell.Text = sSectionName And iStartRow <> 0) Or InStr(1, rCell.Text, "total", vbTextCompare) <> 0 Then
        Else
            If iStartRow = 0 Then
                sSectionName = rCell.Text
                iStartRow = iRow
            Else
                iStopRow = iRow - 1
                CopySheet osh, iFirstRow, iStartRow, iStopRow, iTotalRows, sFilePath, sSectionName, owb.fileFormat
                iCount = iCount + 1
                iStartRow = 0
                iStopRow = 0
                iRow = iRow - 1
            End If
        End If
        If iRow < iTotalRows Then
            iRow = iRow + 1
        Else
            iStopRow = iRow
            CopySheet osh, iFirstRow, iStartRow, iStopRow, iTotalRows, sFilePath, sSectionName, owb.fileFormat
            iCount = iCount + 1
            Exit Do
        End If
    Loop
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
Public Sub DeleteRows(targetSheet As Worksheet, RowFrom As Long, RowTo As Long)
    Dim rngRange As Range
    Set rngRange = Range(targetSheet.Cells(RowFrom, 1), targetSheet.Cells(RowTo, 1)).EntireRow
    rngRange.Select
    rngRange.Delete
End Sub
Public Sub CopySheet(osh As Worksheet, iFirstRow As Long, iStartRow As Long, iStopRow As Long, iTotalRows As Long, sFilePath As String, sSectionName As String, fileFormat As XlFileFormat)
    Dim ash As Worksheet
    Dim awb As Workbook
    osh.Copy
    Set ash = Application.ActiveSheet
    If iTotalRows > iStopRow Then
        DeleteRows ash, iStopRow + 1, iTotalRows
    End If
    If iStartRow > iFirstRow Then
        DeleteRows ash, iFirstRow, iStartRow - 1
    End If
    ash.Cells(1, 1).Select
    sSectionName = Replace(sSectionName, "/", " ")
    sSectionName = Replace(sSectionName, "", " ")
    sSectionName = Replace(sSectionName, ":", " ")
    sSectionName = Replace(sSectionName, "=", " ")
    sSectionName = Replace(sSectionName, "*", " ")
    sSectionName = Replace(sSectionName, ".", " ")
    sSectionName = Replace(sSectionName, "?", " ")
    ash.SaveAs sFilePath + "\Split" + "Order Report " + sSectionName, fileFormat
    Set awb = ash.Parent
    awb.Close SaveChanges:=False
End Sub


Sub getsheets()
    Path = "C:\Users\Jessica\Desktop\Split"
    Filename = Dir(Path & "*.xlsm")
    Do While Filename <> ""
        Workbooks.Open Filename:=Path & Filename, ReadOnly:=True
        For Each Sheet In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
            Sheet.Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
        Next Sheet
        Workbooks(Filename).Close
        Filename = Dir()
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: You'll need to provide sample data and expected results.  Also, you make it sound like your originally have a single master workbook that already has all the information you need.  Can you please clarify?